# How to split a text file bit by bit into two files

Tags: c, file

How can I split a text file into two other files bit by bit. I need all the even numbered bits in file A and all the odd ones in B. In other words, if File X is:

0101010111110000

Then File A would be: 00001100
and B would be: 11111100

Then I need to save those as .txt files. After that, I will need to merge them back together to get X again.

I am using c. 
The code I have so far is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printchar( unsigned char to_print )
{
    unsigned char mask = 0x80;
    for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
    {
       if( (mask & to_print) > 0 )
       {
           printf( "%d", 1 );
       }
       else
       {
           printf( "%d", 0 );
       }
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

void split( unsigned char * left, unsigned char * right, unsigned char input1, unsigned char input2 )
{
    unsigned char mask = 0x80;
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        (*left) |= ( (input1 & mask) << i );
        (*left) |= ( (input2 & mask) >> (4-i) );

        mask = mask >> 1;

        (*right) |= ( (input1 & mask) << (i+1) );
        (*right) |= ( (input2 & mask) >> (3-i) );

        mask = mask >> 1;

    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned char left = 0;
    unsigned char right = 0;
    unsigned char input1 = 0xA6;
    unsigned char input2 = 0xB5;

    split( &left, &right, input1, input2 );
    printchar( left );
    printchar( right );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you have that wall of code, what is wrong with it? Does it fail to compile, blow up when it runs, run without complaint but do the wrong thing... ?

Answer (score 0):

read char by char

in youre code build two buffer chars one with even and other with odd bits
to fully build 2 chars you need to read 2 chars from file
when you have read 4 chars from input file you can write 2 chars you have built
and so one

for part to same approach but in reverse.
You should be careful with the order of reading /writing even/odd bits